# Ajax call between two tomcats

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp

I am Calling a jsp(which is in another tomcat) using ajax function.But i am getting any response back ..I placed my code below

**This is my ajax function(In tomcatA)**

```
function connect(){
try{
// Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
var xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}catch (e){
// Internet Explorer
try {
xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
}catch (e) {
try {
xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}catch (e) {
alert("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
return false;
}
}
}
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
alert(xmlHttp.status);
if(xmlHttp.readyState==4){
}
}
url="http://IP:PORT/List/Get.jsp";
xmlHttp.open("GET",url+"?sid="+Math.random(),true);
xmlHttp.send(null);
}
```

**Below is my Get.jsp(In tomcatB)**

```
<%@page import=" "%>
<%@page import=" "%>
<select>
<%Iterator it = HashMap.keySet().iterator();
while(it.hasNext()){
String key = (String)it.next();
String value = (String)HashMap.get(key);
%>
<option><%= key + " " + value %> </option>
<%}%>

</select>
```

But if i access the Get.jsp directly from browser its work fine.. i am getting the combo box with data(as i expected).Please help me on this.. i swear URL and all right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ajax is used between two different tomcats. if we done the below setting

**IE-->Tools-->Internet Options-->security-->custom level-->miscellaneous-->Access data source Accross domains-->Enable**

this setting should be done in requesting IE side

Answer (score 2):

onreadystatechange is not closed correctly, change the following code:

```
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
   alert(xmlHttp.status);
   if(xmlHttp.readyState==4){
}
```

into this:

```
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    alert(xmlHttp.status);
    if(xmlHttp.readyState==4){
        // do sth
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript can only load data from the same host, this is called [SameOrginPolicy](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Same_origin_policy). In short, this roughly means that a JavaScript Code embedded in a HTML-File on ServerA can only requests documents from ServerA via AJAX. This is done for security reasons.

If you really need to load data from a external server, you can try to use [JSONP](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/JSONP). Examples can be found via Google, for example [here.](http://www.onlinesolutionsdevelopment.com/blog/web-development/javascript/jsonp-example/)